# glfw3 missing gl refrences

Tags: opengl, symbols, glfw

I have created a very bare-bones glfw3 application however when I compile it, I get the following errors:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:11: error: ‘GL_COLOR_BIT_BUFFER’ was not declared in this scope
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void) {

    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwInit();
    glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Hello OpenGL!", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BIT_BUFFER);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}
```

the GL headers are being included from GL/gl.h automatically from the glfw3.h header, yet it can't find the symbol. This would have been found on glfw 2.x, but I am using the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`, not `GL_COLOR_BIT_BUFFER`...

Comment: My bad, I was trying to recreate this from memory mostly, but failed to notice that change.

Comment: @user2216833 - that's because you're not setting `window` to the pointer returned from `glfwCreateWindow`.